# Like in hibernate named query

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, named-query

I added named query in my hbm.xml file and is not working, as code below.

```
<query name="ca.getChildCategories"><![CDATA[
from category as ca where ca.name like :name
        ]]></query>
```

and am calling it as

```
getHibernateTemplate().findByNamedQueryAndNamedParam("ca.getChildCategories" , 
                                new String[] { "name"},
                                new Object[] { likeKey});
```

The application is not able to UP. Any help wil be very much appreciated.

Comment: add the stacktrace pls. i guess your class is `Category` not `category`

Comment: check with `from Category ca where ca.name like :name`

Comment: @Apostolos Thanks . Its my mistake. :)

Comment: i posted my answer. i'd appreciate if you accepted it since it worked. thank you and glad i helped! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please use `from Category ca where ca.name like :name`
dont use `as` when writing hql queries.